# Letting traces around the code

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

There is some performance issue if I let my traces around the whole code when releasing?

```
trace("thank you");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traces are ignored in release builds so there is no performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a performance issue if you have traces active

Some compilers have specific compiler options stating something similar to "build release client", these might or might not end up with a build where all trace-comments does not exist [are ignored].

Even if you don't have anything listening to trace-statements and they are running, it will first of all do an extra function-call and checking some if-statements, then after that it will be stored inside a log-file on the computer where it is run.

So, you should find out what compiler you have and if that one automatically removes trace-messages when compiling in "release mode". If not, you have to either ignore the performance loss or find ways to work around it